# Is it possible to do deep linking with a Blazor Server application?

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

A serious limitation of Blazor WASM is that deep linking in a RESTful scheme is impossible, i.e. `<myDomain>/Units/<unitId>` will work only if you start at myDomain, but not if you give someone the link to a specific unit. A deep link to a unit will return a '404: Not Found' error. This can be solved with `<myDomain>?UnitId=<unitId>` but for various reasons this is problematic.

This limitation is shared ASFAIK with other SPA frameworks, for obvious reasons.

Is deep linking possible for BLAZOR sever? Will .NET 8 make it all easier with one of the new Blazor modes?

I am currently on .NET 7.

***Edit***
An example of what I mean can be seen by following these steps:

1. Go [here](https://wonderful-pond-09783fa10.3.azurestaticapps.net/)
2. Enter `Amsterdam` in search box and click the button
3. click one of the resulting cards, which will navigate to something like `https://wonderful-pond-09783fa10.3.azurestaticapps.net/Places/Details/550`
4. Copy the URI and paste it in a different browser - you should get a 404, to my understanding because the SPA does not know of the route /Places/Details.

What I am trying to do is to be able to link directly into this type of URI.

Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me why you think `/Units/{unitId}` won't work.  It's just another route.

Comment: It doesn't work in the context of deep linking, so obviously in the application navigating to such a link will work if the route exists, but if you give this link to someone to go to directly without starting at the default page, it will fail. There are many references for this.

Comment: In the first version it wasn't so clear. And I when I try this on Kestrel (localhost) it just works. So I don't think it's entirely a Blazor or SPA problem.

Comment: You may want to look at "static serverside rendering" in dotnet8 (rc). Could be what you need.

Comment: OK, maybe not 1000!  But a load of text normally needs some context to really understand! ;-).  Anyway, this looks like a Fallback Route issue which happens when you use a static provider [such as an Azure Static App].  What you need is for the provider to return `index.html` whatever the url requested.  There's an MS article that covers this here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor#fallback-route.

Comment: Step 1 to 4 work as expected. The URL from step 4 did open in a second browser https://wonderful-pond-09783fa10.3.azurestaticapps.net/Places/Details/550 and did return the page as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As MrC suggested, adding a `staticwebapp.config.json` file to the wwwroot folder with the contents:

```
{
  "navigationFallback": {
    "rewrite": "/index.html"
  }
}
```

causes Azure (in my case) to serve the application regardless of the requested route.